How to parse json in flutter Dart
{0: {id: 1, user_id: 1, title: Group A, open: true}, 1: {id: 2, user_id: 1, title: yiuyi, open: false}, pagination: {total: 2, per_page: 10, current_page: 1, last_page: 1, next_page_url: null, prev_page_url: null}}

how can i parse each value in dart

Try below code to parse json data
Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>> data = {0: {id: 1, user_id: 1, title: Group A, open: true}, 1: {id: 2, user_id: 1, title: yiuyi, open: false}, pagination: {total: 2, per_page: 10, current_page: 1, last_page: 1, next_page_url: null, prev_page_url: null}}

  print('data-> 0: ${data[0]}');
  print('data-> 1: ${data[1]}');

  Map<String, dynamic> pagination = data['pagination'];
  int totalItems = pagination['total'];
  int currentPage = pagination['current_page'];

  print('Total items: $totalItems');
  print('Current page: $currentPage');
}

for dynamic 0,1,2... take data in forEach loop with if data key is int then get 0,1,2 json data else pagination data.
 data.forEach((key, value) {
    if (key is int) {
      print('Data for key $key:');
      print('id: ${value['id']}');
      print('user_id: ${value['user_id']}');
      print('title: ${value['title']}');
      print('open: ${value['open']}');
    } else if (key == 'pagination') {
      Map<String, dynamic> pagination = value;
      int totalItems = pagination['total'];
      int currentPage = pagination['current_page'];
      print('Pagination:');
      print('Total items: $totalItems');
      print('Current page: $currentPage');
    }


0 and 1 value is dynamic and it grow like 0 ,1,2 more and each have value , how we can set dynamic parse

I have edited answer, hope it helps...
